# Trust relationship between domains

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am working in a organisation where it has a structure of a parent company and a subsidiary.
Both are individual domains without trust.

I work for the subsidiary

The requirement is that the subsidiary company should have access to a ticketing portal at the parent company.
This application relies on the parent company's AD for authentication.
So what kind of trust relationship should we have.
Can anyone please elaborate please, I really need your advice

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In a trust relationship, the two domains are referred to as the trusting domain and the trusted domain. The trusted domain is the domain where the trust relationship is created. The trusting domain is the other domain specified in the trust, that is, the one wherein network resources can to be accessed. The trusting domain in this case recognizes the logon authentications of the trusted domain. [This](http://www.tech-faq.com/understanding-trust-relationships.html) helps to know the details about understanding trust model in Windows NT domain. This [source](https://tnind.wordpress.com/how-to-set-up-a-trust-relationship-between-two-domains/) will help you to setup the trust relation between two domains.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you simply have to [remove the computer from the domain and rejoin again](http://www.lauramartin.co.nz/fix-the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-domain-failed/). You can do via Active Directory I believe or Powershell. But I've found that this is the most simplest and straightforward way...and can be done from the offending computer or remotely if necessary.

Comment: The question refers to a trust between Active Directory domains, which is a separate concept to repairing the trust relationship between a workstation and its assigned domain.